# Mockito rest template is always null for mocked object

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, mockito

When mocking a class which contains a rest template, the rest template is always null, my code is:

```
public class ClassA {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ClassA(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public byte[] method(String url) {
       // do some restTemplate.getForObject()
    }
}

   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
public class TestClass {

    @Mock
    private ClassA classa

     public void test1() {

      Mockito.doReturn(byeArray).when(classA).method("url");
     }
}
```

When inspecting the line  Mockito.doReturn(byeArray).when(classA).method("url"); i notice that the object classA contains the rest template but it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking is done on dependencies, not on the class under test. there are ways to mock on the class under test methods also, that can be done using `Spy`.

In your current case, it should be like this.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
public class TestClass {

    @InjectMock
    private ClassA classa

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate

    @Test
    public void test1() {
      Mockito.doReturn(byeArray).when(restTemplate).method(url);
   }
}
```

Class under test `ClassA` should be annotated with `@InjectMocks` and dependencies should be mocked using `@Mock`.

Another thing to note, in your test case, you should call `ClassA` method which needs to be tested.

```
@Test
public void test1() {
  Mockito.doReturn(byeArray).when(restTemplate).doSomething(url);

  classa.method(url);
}
```

Comment: Understand what you are saying, one further question though, Mockito.doReturn(byeArray).when(restTemplate).doSomething(url); this wont work as doSomething() is a method of classA and not of restemplate

Comment: @SEED if you want to control method of `classA` itself, you should explore concept called `Spying`.  though that wouldn't be good practice to do. if your `doSomething` method is private, I would still recommend, not to mock that. mocking should be done to external dependencies. I hope this helps.

Comment: if your other method `doSomething()`, calls `RestTemplate`, try mocking that `RestTemplate` call.